# Storing select option input value in React component inside MongoDB - MERN fail. Stores it as empty string

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am working with MERN and trying to store select option input values in my MongoDb database using mongoose. Like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Admin extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        //setting initial states
        this.state= {
            college: ''
        }
    }

onChangeCollege=(event)=>{
        this.setState({college: event.target.value})
    }

 onSubmit =(event) =>{
        event.preventDefault()

        console.log('Form Submitted')

        const newCourse = {
            college:this.state.college
        }

        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/courses/admin', newCourse)
            .then(response => console.log(response.data))
            .catch(() => console.log('Error creating new course'))

        this.setState({
            college: ''
                    })
    }

   

    render(){
        
    return (
        <div className="space3">
            <h3>Add a Course to the Database</h3>
        <form autoComplete="on" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className="space"> 
            <div className="form-group">
                 <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">COLLEGE</label>
                     <select className="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" >
                        <option defaultValue>Choose...</option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > College of 
 Agricultural and Environmental Sciences </option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > College of Humanities and Social Sciences </option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > College of Education and External Studies </option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > College of Health Sciences </option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > College of Natural Sciences </option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > College of Business and Management Studies </option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > College of Engineering, Design,  Art and Technology </option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > College of Veterinary Medicine, Animal Resources and Bio-Security </option>
                        <option value={this.state.college} onChange={this.onChangeCollege} > School of Law </option>
                    </select>
 </div>
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

            </form>
            </div>
    )
    }
}

export default Admin;
```

my backend is Nodejs which looks like this.
THE MODEL

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Courses = new mongoose.Schema({
    college: {
        type:String
    }  
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('coursesmodel', Courses)
```

THE API

```
const express = require ('express')
const router = express.Router()
const coursedb = require('../models/coursedb')

//add new todo to list
router.post('/admin', (request, response) => {
    const list = new coursedb({
        college: request.body.college
    })

    list.save()
    .then(courses => {response.json(courses)})
    .catch(error => {response.json(error)})
})
 
module.exports = router
```

As you can see in my console, that last console.log returns an empty string for the COLLEGE value.

[image: As you can see in my console, that last console.log returns an empty string for the COLLEGE value.]

And this is what it looks like in my MongoDB.

[image: And this is what it looks like in my MongoDB.]

How do i store that COLLEGE input select option in my db as a String, like the rest, and not an empty String. Need help!

Comment: are you sure this.state.college is not an empty string? all of your option value is set to `this.state.college`

Answer (score 2):

In the state, `college` is an empty string and in the JSX code, `value` of each options is `this.state.college`, i.e. an empty string and this is where your problem is.

Whenever `onChangeCollege()` is triggered, `event.target.value` is the value of the `value` attribute of the `option` element that triggered the `onChange` event, and in your case, it is `this.state.college`, i.e. an empty string and that is what you are sending to the server when form is submitted.

`value` attribute of the `option` element should be equal to the value of the option that is visible to the user. For example, you need to change

```
<option
  value={this.state.college}
  onChange={this.onChangeCollege}
>
  College of Humanities and Social Sciences
</option>
```

to

```
<option
  value="College of Humanities and Social Sciences"
  onChange={this.onChangeCollege}
>
  College of Humanities and Social Sciences
</option>
```

You need to do this for all of the `option` elements.

---

**Side note:** You don't need to add a separate `onChange` listener on each `option`, adding `onChange` event listener on the `select` element will achieve the same result.

```
<select
  className="custom-select"
  id="inputGroupSelect01"
  onChange={this.onChangeCollege} 
>
  ...
</select>
```

If you want to know why this works, see: [`MDN - Event Bubbling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture)

Comment: Your solution totally worked!. Thank you so much @yousaf . I'm so happy to be past this bug now.